# Flutter - How to fix this difference between iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm learning Flutter and so, I am doing some test. In my last test app, I have implemented an ExpansionPanel with icons inside. The icons shows on iOS but not on Android. Any idea why and how to fix this ?

```
    new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
            Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.time_to_leave, size: _iconSize, color: _iconColor),
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _textPadding)),
                    Text("Car", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: _fontSize))
                ],
            ),

        ],
    ),
```

The [first](https://ibb.co/LQYPgFz) screenshot is from the iOS emulator (expected result) and the [second](https://ibb.co/52p7tnF) one from the Android emulator (the wrong one). The results are the same when the application is built.

Edit, as asked, the full code (I removed useless parts that do not change the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Criterias extends StatefulWidget {
  CriteriaState createState() => new CriteriaState();
}

class NewItem {
  bool isExpanded;
  final String header;
  final Widget body;
  final Icon iconpic;
  NewItem(this.isExpanded, this.header, this.body, this.iconpic);
}

double discretevalue = 2.0;
double hospitaldiscretevalue = 25.0;

class CriteriaState extends State<Criterias> {

  bool firstStart = true;
  List<NewItem> items;
  final double _textPadding = 4;
  final double _fontSize = 20;
  final double _panelPadding = 15.0;
  int _bottomNavigationBarIndex = 0;
  static bool _defaultExpanded = true;
  bool _expandOrCollapse = _defaultExpanded;
  Color _iconColor = Colors.lightBlue;

  void _expandCollapse () {
    setState(() {
      _expandOrCollapse = !_expandOrCollapse;
      for (var item in items) {
        item.isExpanded = _expandOrCollapse;
      }
    });
  }

  void onTabTaped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      print(index);
      _bottomNavigationBarIndex = index;
    });
  }

  ListView List_Criteria;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (firstStart) {
      firstStart = false;
      double _iconSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6;
      items = <NewItem>[
        new NewItem(
            _defaultExpanded,
            'Travel',
            new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(_panelPadding),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.time_to_leave, size: _iconSize, color: _iconColor),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _textPadding)),
                            Text("Car", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: _fontSize))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ]
                    ),

                    new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),

                    new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.timeline, size: _iconSize, color: _iconColor),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _textPadding)),
                            Text("Path", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: _fontSize))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ]
                    ),
                  ],
                )
                  ),
            new Icon(Icons.time_to_leave),
        ),
      ];
    }

    List_Criteria = new ListView(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
          child: 
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _expandCollapse(),
                  child: Text(_expandOrCollapse ? "Collapse All" : "Expand All", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontSize: 15)),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
              ],
            ),
        ),

        new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: new ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
              setState(() {
                items[index].isExpanded = !items[index].isExpanded;
              });
            },
            children: items.map((NewItem item) {
              return new ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                  return new ListTile(
                      leading: item.iconpic,
                      title: new Text(
                        item.header,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ));
                },
                isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
                body: item.body,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );

    Scaffold scaffold = new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Application"),
      ),
      body: _bottomNavigationBarIndex == 0 ? List_Criteria : Container(
        child:
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8),
                child: 
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      //CloseButton()
                      Icon(Icons.close, size: 30)
                    ],
                  ),
              ),

              Divider(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),

              Container(),
            ],
          )
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: 
      BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTaped,
        currentIndex: _bottomNavigationBarIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items:<BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money), title: Text("Payment")),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money), title: Text("Payment")),
    ]
      ),
    );
    return scaffold;
  }
}


void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home:Criterias()));
}
```

Comment: can you post full code? Then I can check the issue

Comment: @IshanFernando I edited the question by adding the code, as asked

Comment: I run this code and It shows Icon in android

Comment: Even when building the app ? Because now I see it working in the emulator (API 26) but not when running it on my phone (API 26 too)

Comment: It tested on my test device which have API 26 and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after digging in Flutter Bug Tracker, it appears that there is a bug in Flutter when using large characters/icons. The icons randomly show up on some devices and not on others.